# I am trying to give an active className to mapped data when I click. Currently the previous active class doesn't change when i click on another text

Tags: reactjs

**Parent component**

> Here is the mapped function

```
function SubHeader() {
  const categories = category?.data?.data;
  return (
            {categories?.map((data) => (

          <Smaller data={data} />

        ))}  );
}
```

**Child component**
Here is where I am using the state to control the color of the text when it is clicked. Not sure I can figure what isn't right.

```
function Smaller({ data }) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
   const colorPicker = (dataId) => {
    setActive(dataId ? !active : active);
  };

  return (
    <Text
      color={active ? 'brand.blue' : 'brand.dark'}
      onClick={() => colorPicker(data?.id)}
    >
      {data?.name}
    </Text>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you click on another text, it **doesn't change the active state of other / previous texts**. So you're just toggling the active class of each  component but it doesn't "untoggle" anywhere.
I found a way to solve this but I used a simple example because I didn't have your data.

**Solution:**

1. Each child component should have an ID.
2. Check if the child component's ID matches the activeElementID.

**Parent Component**

```
function SubHeader() {
  const [activeElementID, setActiveElementID] = useState()
  const categories = category?.data?.data;

  return (
    {categories?.map((data) => {
      <Smaller data = {data} id = {data?.id} activeElementID={activeElementID} setActiveElementID={setActiveElementID} />
    })}
  )
}
```

**Child Component**

```
function Smaller({data, id, activeElementID, setActiveElementID}) {

  function clicked() {
    setActiveElementID(id)
  }

  return (
    <p onClick={clicked} className={activeElementID === id ? "blue" : "red"}>{data}</p>
  )
}
```

---

Furthermore, I would also recommend checking the data instead of using  the "?" operation. For example, category?.data and data?.data

Because you are saying that you are **sure** the data exists. You can do this instead.

```
const categories = category.data.data
if (categories) {
   return (....)
}
```

Hope this helps!